# Boolean Algebra - Minimization

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a problem with this assignment:

The 26th one:

[image]

I am supposed to minimize this, and I get to

" XY + ZY + ( Z*(inverted X) )"

But solution to this problem is 
[image]

I don't know how to minimize more the solution I got up there :/

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

See if this makes sense...  `z+y` goes away because the OR function is handled by the other two that have those inputs.  Best way to do this is draw a K-map.  I used `xy` on the vertical axis, and `z` on the horizontal and the equation `(x+z)(!x+y)` was obvious.

Then, because you expand that equation to `(!xx) + (!xz) + (zy) + (xy)` and notice that `(!xx)` has no contribution, and you create another K-map for the remaining terms (excluding `(!xx)`) the equation `(xy) + (!xz)` becomes obvious.

Comment: Oh... But when you are left with only XY+Z*(! X) + ZY, how do you minimize that without K map, what rules of boolean algebra could we use to minimize it?

Comment: How about...  `!xz + !!z + !!y + xy` = `!x(z+z) + x(y+y)` = `!xz+xy` Assuming, I applied that DeMorgan's identity correctly for the `zy` term... I dunno, could be crap-math :/

Comment: To what identity did you apply deMorgan? How did you get the. !xz +!!z +!!y + xy

Comment: `zy = (!!z+!!y)`

Answer (score 1):

Given that (x+z)(/x+y), there are four conditions in which it can be true.  We can eliminate one of them, x/x, as it is always false. That leaves xy+/xz+yz.  The third term is redundant, since if yz is true, one of the preceding terms will be true depending on the value of x.